# Can I mount a drive using UUID from the command-line (Not fstab?)

Tags: debian, command-line, mount

Is it possible to use UUIDs to mount drives, rather than using these values in fstab?

I have a script which mounts devices, however there is no way to guarantee that the drive labels such as `/dev/sda2` will always be the same.

I'm aware I can mount the drive at boot time using this method with `fstab`, however in the case of external disks, they may not always be present at boot time.

Comment: FYI having an entry in fstab does not mean you need the drive connected at boot time. `mount` will use the data in fstab when called.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you just use the `UUID` option:

```
lsblk -o NAME,UUID
NAME      UUID
sdc       
├─sdc1    A190-92D5
└─sdc2    A198-A7BC

sudo mount -U A198-A7BC /mnt
```

Or

```
sudo mount UUID=A198-A7BC /mnt
```

Or

```
sudo mount --uuid A198-A7BC /mnt
```

The `mount --help`:

```
Source:
 -L, --label      synonym for LABEL=
 -U, --uuid        synonym for UUID=
 LABEL=           specifies device by filesystem label
 UUID=             specifies device by filesystem UUID
 PARTLABEL=       specifies device by partition label
 PARTUUID=         specifies device by partition UUID
                 specifies device by path
              mountpoint for bind mounts (see --bind/rbind)
                   regular file for loopdev setup
```

Comment: Linux is so great. Thanks, had no clue about these options

Answer (score 15):

If you're interested in having an `fstab` entry for a drive which may not be present at boot time, you have two options which can help: [`noauto` and `nofail`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html):

> `noauto`: do not mount when "mount -a" is given (e.g., at boot time)
>
> `nofail`: do not report errors for this device if it does not exist.

Imagine you have an `fstab` entry

```
UUID={YOUR-UID}    /mnt/data      ext4    defaults
```

If you add `noauto` to the options, the system will not attempt to mount the drive at boot time. You'll be able to mount it manually with `mount /mnt/data`.

If you add `nofail`, the system will try to mount the drive at boot time, but if the drive is not present the boot sequence will not be interrupted. You'll be able to mount the drive if you plug it later using `mount /mnt/data`.

Comment: I guess the advantage of this is that users can mount without `sudo` as well?

Comment: @user3728501 if you add `user` option in the options column, then yes.

Comment: @Ruslan Very nice, thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can use the system-provided symlinks:

```
mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/{YOUR_UUID} /mnt
```